# Унифицированные шаблоны представления для PHP и JS

Tags: php, javascript, шаблонизаторы

Существуют ли шаблонизаторы, которые возможно применять как на стороне backend (PHP), так и на стороне frontend (JS)? В частности интересует решение, позволяющее использовать единый синтаксис в шаблоне и реализующее три основные операции:

1. Вставка переменных
2. Условие
3. Цикл

Прикладной задачей является реализация виджетов, которые возможно рендерить на backend:

```
<ul>
  <?php foreach($todos as $todo): ?>
    <!-- Дублирующийся шаблон -->
    <li><?= $todo->content ?></li>
  <?php endforeach; ?>
  <li>
    <input type="button" value="add"/>
  </li>
</ul>
```

с добавлением логики на уровне frontend и последующим изменением состояния путем применения тех же шаблонов:

```
function TodoListView(ul){
  var $ul = $(ul),
    // Дублирующийся шаблон
    liTemplate = tempalte('<li>{todo.content}</li>');
  $ul.find('input:button').on('click', function(){
    $ul.prepend(liTemplate({
      content: 'FooBar'
    }));
  });
}
```

Comment: Twig, pug, handlebars, ... тысячи их. Но лучше рендерить все шаблоны в каком-то одном месте

Comment: Twig умеет работать на JS?
Pug и handlebars умеет работать на PHP?

Понятно что лучше не дублировать логику, но легаси и задачи такие, что нужно как то решить проблему с двойной шаблонизацией.

Comment: Есть порты Twig на js, как впрочем и порты Pug и Handlebars на PHP. Если хочется очень-очень большой кроссплатформенности, можно попробовать mustache - оно реализовано на очень большом количестве языков.

Comment: А разве синтаксис не будет отличаться, к примеру {{ $var }} и {{ var }} ?

Comment: Нет, синтаксис один-в-один.

Comment: А как же быть с include? К примеру на уровне backend необходимо использовать абсолютные адреса до подключаемых блоков, а во frontend компоновать блоки уже придется с помощью самого JS (без include).

Comment: Выберите шаблонизатор и почитайте документацию. В handlebars, например, это называется partials